# Declaring Variables in a For Loop

Tags: sensors

I am trying to use a for loop for getting readings on two parallax ping sensors and want to find the difference between both readings.

But am having trouble doing so. Whenever I declare `print ping(1)`, I don't actually get the value of ping(1). *How can I have two variables for ping(0) and ping(1)* that I can call whenever I want and have them be accurate.

## Code

```cpp
int ultraSoundSignalPins[] = {5,7}; 
int tx = 4;
char *pingString[] = {"Ping1 ","Ping2 "}; // just something to print to indicate direction

void setup()
{
 Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{

 unsigned long ultrasoundValue;
 for(int i=0; i < 2; i++)
 {
   ultrasoundValue = ping(i);
   Serial.print(pingString[i]);
   Serial.print(ultrasoundValue);
   Serial.print("cm, ");    
   delay(500);
  
 }
} 

//Ping function
unsigned long ping(int i)
{
 unsigned long echo;

 pinMode(ultraSoundSignalPins[i], OUTPUT); // Switch signalpin to output
 pinMode(tx, OUTPUT);          
 digitalWrite(ultraSoundSignalPins[i], LOW); // Send low pulse
 digitalWrite(tx, LOW); 
 delayMicroseconds(2); // Wait for 2 microseconds
 digitalWrite(ultraSoundSignalPins[i], HIGH); // Send high pulse
 digitalWrite(tx, HIGH);
 delayMicroseconds(5); // Wait for 5 microseconds
 digitalWrite(ultraSoundSignalPins[i], LOW); // Holdoff
 pinMode(ultraSoundSignalPins[i], INPUT); // Switch signalpin to input
 digitalWrite(ultraSoundSignalPins[i], HIGH); // Turn on 0pullup resistor
 echo = pulseIn(ultraSoundSignalPins[i], HIGH); //Listen for echo
 return (echo / 29.1); //convert to CM then to inches
}
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Where did you put the print statement, what did you expect, and what did get printed instead?

Comment: I'd convert `ultrasoundValue` into an array, just like `ultraSoundSignalPins`. That way you can retrieve both values using `ultraSoundSignalPins[0]` and `ultraSoundSignalPins[1]`

Comment: can you maybe lead me to how i would do that

Comment: `unsigned long ultrasoundValue[2]` and `ultrasoundValue[i] = ping(i);`.